# MongoDB aggregate on multiple fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have only experience with RDBS. There is it possible to aggregate fields by more than one field.

```
t_example:

country  |  city   |   val  |  useless
---------------------------------------
Ger      |  Ber    |    10  |    abc
Ger      |  Ber    |    10  |    abc
Ger      |  MU     |    10  |    abc
FR       |  Par    |    10  |    abc
```

SELECT country,city,sum(val) FROM t_example GROUP BY country,city;

=>

```
country  |  city   |   val  
----------------------------
Ger      |  Ber    |    20  
Ger      |  MU     |    10  
FR       |  Par    |    10
```

Is it possible to get the same result by MongoDB if a collection contains the same Values on JSON files?
I tried this on NodeJS:

```
dbs.collection('t_example').aggregate([{ $group: { "_id": "$country","count":{$sum:1}}}]).toArray(function(error,result){
            res.json(result);       
        });
```

I got a similiar result:

```
[{"_id":"Ger","count":30},{"_id":"Fr","count":10}]
```

Is it possible to break down the data by an additional field (city)? 
I also can´t change the key (_id). Otherwise the result is an empty Array.

Comment: _id takes document. Try _`id:{country:"$country", city:"$city"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following pipeline.

```
[
  { $group: { 
    _id: { country: "$country", city: "$city" }, 
    val: { $sum: "$val" } 
  } }
]
```

In fact, for a group stage, `_id` [can be a structured object](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#group-by-month-day-and-year).

The resulting documents look like this.

```
[
    {
        "_id" : {
            "country" : "Fr",
            "city" : "Par"
        },
        "val" : 10.0
    },
    {
        "_id" : {
            "country" : "Ger",
            "city" : "MU"
        },
        "val" : 10.0
    },
    {
        "_id" : {
            "country" : "Ger",
            "city" : "Ber"
        },
        "val" : 20.0
    }
]
```